# pagespeed (chrome) not recognizing javascript defer

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, pagespeed

After I read pagespeed (chrome) suggestion to defer javascript, I modified the javascript link tag for three files, not all files.

However, when I load the website, pagespeed continues to suggest that I defer javascript, and the modified files continue to appear under the suggestion's list.

I have attached two images, one shows that pagespeed is suggesting I defer these javascript files, and the other is showing the pagesource, which lcearly shows that the javascript link tag includes the defer attribute.

PAGE SPEED IMAGE

[image: pagespeed suggest I defer javascript files which according to page source have been deferred]

WEB PAGE SOURCE CODE

[image: webpage source code shows these javascript link tags with defer attribute]

For live website: http://redesign.com.s136249.gridserver.com/

Do you have any insight as to why this is happening (perhaps this files are not being deferred?) do you have any suggestions of what can I do to have pagespeed reflect the deferral of these javascript files?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Consider using the [defer](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/defer/) attribute!

**Old Answer:**

The concept is, that a script loading should be deferred, that is, it should appear after all of your contents.

Like just before the closing `</body>` tag, and that's the right way of saying it as deferred.

For now, what you have done, is just like ordering scripts.

And why is it asking you to defer it?

- Whatever external files you specify in your code, needs an extra call to be loaded.
- Until that call is resolved, the rest of the content of your page cannot be rendered by the browser, and have to wait, until your scripts are loaded.
- Making this call in the initial part of the code, makes your site appear a bit slow.

Comment: I have moved the 3 link files to just right before the </body> tag, you can see this by viewing the source code of the live page. Still, I am getting the same results, page-speed continues to suggest I defer these three files, meanwhile, as I mentioned before, these are position were you suggested. Thoughts?

Comment: @IberoMedia: Consider using the [defer](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/defer/) attribute in your script tag, updated my answer!

Comment: I have added the defer attribute. Results have not changed. If you are loading this page, and if you are running pagespeed to view the results, do you show these files under the deferral suggestion? Thank you

Comment: From the page speed google groups I was directed to this reference http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/mobile.html#DeferParsingJS which suggest an asychronous attribute. Regarding moving the code to before the </body> tag, this document indicates "Note that moving your <script> tags to the end of the page is sub-optimal, since the browser will continue to show a busy indicator until the page has finished parsing this JavaScript." So, I will try to implement what page speed for mobile document suggests, and update then.